# Projection of vectors.

Tags: vectors, projection

[image]

The question asks to calculate $ \vec{ez}$ in function of $\vec{i}$ $\vec{j}$ and $\vec{k}$.

$\alpha=(Ox,Ox_1)=(Oz,Oz_1)$

$\vec{i}$ $\vec{j}$ and $\vec{k}$ being respectively the unit vectors of $OX1$, $OY$ and $OZ1$

$\vec{ez}$ is the unit vector of $Oz$

According to the solution manual : $ \vec{ez}=cos(\alpha)  \vec{k}-sin(\alpha)  \vec{i}$

However i'm not sure how they got to this answer.

Shouldn't it be $ \vec{ez}=cos(\alpha)  \vec{k}$ instead?

Thanks in advance and excuse me for the bad drawing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $z_1-x_1$ seems obtained by a rotation of $z-x$ orthogonal to $y$ then

$$\vec{e_z}=cos(\alpha)  \vec{k}-sin(\alpha)  \vec{i}$$

is correct and

$$\vec{e_x}=sin(\alpha)  \vec{k}+cos(\alpha)  \vec{i}$$

note indeed that $$\vec{e_z}\cdot \vec{e_x}=0$$